# R: Keep function vectroized using all()

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a function `fun` checking multiple conditions `a, b`. If all conditions are fulfilled, the function should return `TRUE`, else it should return `FALSE`.

```
a = 1
b = 0

fun <- function(a, b){
  all(a < 1,
      b < 1,
      na.rm = TRUE)
}

fun(a, b)
```

This function does the trick. However, if I use vectors now, `all()` does of course not keep the vector form but rather returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I would like to have a function that works the same as the following one:

```
a = 1:2
b = 0:1

funV <- function(a, b){
  a < 1 & b < 1
}

funV(a, b)
```

but without chaining `&` and it should also work with missing values.

Comment: `all(all(a < 1),all(b( < 1))`?  Why do you want to avoid `&` - interesting challenge or specific other reason?

Comment: I want to use this function in a `mutate` statement, so I need to keep the vector form. With & it becomes unclean imho, and I wouldn't know how to deal with NA's (edited question).

Comment: The pmin way works like a charm. Is there any reason to accept another vectorized way with less efficiency?

Comment: Sorry if I am handling this incorrectly. But for my intends and purposes, the `Vectorize()` response was the one that I was looking for, as it generally shows how to vectorize functions with a property similar to `all()`. Please let me know if my approach is incorrect with respect to how it should be handled on Stack Overflow, and I will be happy to change the correct answer checkmark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Vectorize()` for this to create a vectorized function. `Vectorize()` uses `mapply()` under the hood.

```r
fun <- function(a,b){
  all(a < 1,
      b < 1,
      na.rm = TRUE)
}

a = 1:2
b = 0:1

funV <- Vectorize(fun)

funV(a,b)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

`pmin` + `as.logical` = vectorized `all()`.

```r
fun <- function(a, b){
  as.logical(pmin(a < 1, b < 1, na.rm = TRUE))
}

fun(1:2, 0:1)
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```

---

##### Benchmark

```r
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#    pmin_all(a, b)   1.816587   1.843934   2.223257   1.868905   3.004286   5.936595   100
#  mapply_all(a, b) 181.204836 183.868243 188.579629 185.331190 188.332364 347.997674   100
#     vec_all(a, b) 186.911905 190.187575 194.159146 192.135094 194.848294 218.416740   100
```

```r
pmin_all <- function(a, b){
  as.logical(pmin(a < 1, b < 1, na.rm = TRUE))
}

mapply_all <- function(a, b){
  mapply(\(x, y) all(x < 1, y < 1, na.rm = TRUE), a, b)
}

vec_all <- Vectorize(function(a, b){
  all(a < 1, b < 1, na.rm = TRUE)
})

a <- rnorm(1e5, mean = 1)
b <- rnorm(1e5, mean = 1)

library(microbenchmark)

bm <- microbenchmark(
  pmin_all(a, b),
  mapply_all(a, b),
  vec_all(a, b),
  check = 'identical'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `mapply`:

```r
fun <- function(a,b){
  mapply(\(x, y) all(x < 1, y < 1, na.rm = TRUE), a, b)
}

fun(1:2, 0:1)
#[1] FALSE FALSE
```